# How do i convert user input to a float or int?

Tags: python

So I have

```
inp = print(input('what is your number?'))
n = float(inp) 
for i in range(1,n):
    print('the derivativ to the', n, 'derivative is', simplify(diff(f,x,i)))
```

and it says I cannot do this because my `n` is a `nonetype` val and not an `int` or `float`, but it wont let me convert to either of those

Comment: In short words: `print` returns `None`. That's what you're doing there, you're assigning `inp` the `None` value. If you want to get the input value and print it on the screen, write `n = input('...')` and then `print(n)`.

Comment: Also, you can't use a `float` in the `range` function. Should you allow a float? If so, it needs to be converted to an integer. Should it be the next lower integer?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you are assigning the return value of a print function, which is `None`, to `inp`.
Try this instead:

```
inp = input('what is your number?')
print(inp)
n = float(inp) 
for i in range(1,n):
    print('the derivativ to the', n, 'derivative is', simplify(diff(f,x,i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below should work for you:

```
n = int(input('what is your number?'))
for i in range(1,n):
    print('the derivativ to the', n, 'derivative is', simplify(diff(f,x,i)))
```

`input` returns a string which you have to explicitly convert to int, like this:

```
n = int(input('what is your number?'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you pass the number input to `print` and then use the result of `print` for your variable. But `print` always returns `None` - you've lost the input. Assign the variable and print in different steps. But don't forget to manage errors. Users are notoriously bad at following instructions.

Notice also that `float` can't be used in the `range` function whose job is to emit integers. Force the user input to be an integer from the get go to avoid errors.

```
while True:
    inp = input('what is your number?')
    print(inp)
    try:
        n = int(inp)
        if n <= 1:
            raise ValueError("Natural numbers greater than 1 only")
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"{e}. Try again.")

for i in range(1,n):
    print('the derivativ to the', n, 'derivative is', simplify(diff(f,x,i)))
```